# Storing a char in an array segfault

Tags: c, char, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a segfault in my code and I'm not sure why. I read through a file and count the number of lines in order to dynamically allocate my arrays. I then rewind the file, read the data in the file, storing the data into variables, and then storing the read variables into arrays, but I'm having trouble with chars.

```
   ...
   char *aname = malloc(sizeof(char) * 3); 
   ... 
   // get # lines in file (count)
   ... 
   char *aname_seen = malloc(count * (sizeof(char) * 3));
   ...
   rewind(file);
   while (fgets(buff, sizeof buff, file) != NULL) 
   {
      if (sscanf(buff, "%s %d %s %s %d %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf\n", 
         atm, &serial, aname, resName, &resSeq, &x, &y, &z, 
         &occupancy, &tempFactor) == 10)
      {
         aname_seen[i] = *aname;
         printf("%d: %s vs %s\n", i, aname, aname_seen[i]);

         i++;

      } // end sscanf if-loop

   } // end while loop
```

I can print aname with `printf("%d: %s\n", i, aname)` and get the expected output, but I'm getting `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` when I try `printf("%d: %s vs %s\n", i, aname, aname_seen[i])`.

This while loop + nested if loop is the same convention I use to count the number of lines, so `i` will increment up to count. Am I incorrectly allocating aname_seen and not actually giving it `count` number of `char*3` elements? I'm not well versed in messing with char's. More of a numerical fortran buff, so I need some direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Suggest preventing potential buffer overrun by specifying the maximum number of characters assign to a string by `sscanf()`. This can be done by replacing the `"%s"` format specifier with `"%Ns"` where `N` is one less than the number of characters in the array being populated.

Comment: You don't appear to initialise `i`. Has that just been elided?

Comment: Are you aware that `aname_seen[i] = *aname;` only copies a single character?

Comment: @interjay, I do now realize this. I asked about how to fix that on modifiable lvalue's answer. If you have a solution, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: @Chowlett, it has been initialized, just not shown in this snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%s` format specifier is supposed to correspond to a `char *` argument. In your case, `aname_seen[i]` is a `char`, which gets promoted to an `int` for the purpose of passing to a variadic function (`printf`). An `int` is not a `char *`.

Perhaps you meant one of these:

```
printf("%d: %s vs %c\n", i, aname, aname_seen[i]);
printf("%d: %s vs %s\n", i, aname, &aname_seen[i]);
```

If neither of these solve your problem, please explain precisely the behaviour you expect from this expression and give us a minimal, compilable testcase. Your current testcase isn't compilable.

Comment: This solved the print out problem, but another arises. Some of these aname's are things like HA, CA, etc., but aname_seen only stores the first character of those strings. Is there any way to modify aname_seen so that it can store the entirety of what aname contains?

Comment: There sure is a way to modify aname_seen so that it can store the entirety of what aname contains. I'm sure the book you're reading covers this topic fairly early on.

Comment: Book I'm reading? This is for drug production code in industry.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't learn C by trial and error, or by unguided example (modifying copy/pasted code). C has a concept known as "undefined behaviour", which is undesirable. One example of undefined behaviour is the topic of your question: The code that causes your segfaults. Segfaults aren't required, however. A program that invokes undefined behaviour may seem to work on some systems, but only by coincidence. On other systems, such a program might malfunction in subtle or devastating ways (such as producing segfaults). You need to learn C from a book in order to avoid undefined behaviour.

Comment: @mjswartz You've demonstrated a confusion between the type of c in `char c;` and the type of p in `char *p;`. The `*` is significant, in that it denotes a pointer. A book will explain the difference in detail, as well as the standard C function for copying strings (`strcpy`). I suggest K&Rs "The C Programming Language", second edition.

Answer (score 1):

you way you defined `aname_seen` is a pointer to a char array

```
char *aname_seen = malloc(count * (sizeof(char) * 3));
```

so `aname_seen[i]` is a `char`

so the

```
printf("%d: %s vs %s\n", i, aname, aname_seen[i]);
```

should be

```
printf("%d: %s vs %c\n", i, aname, aname_seen[i]);
```